# playing a video in a python program on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wxpython

I have a Raspberry Pi 3+, python 3.7, wx, and gstreamer. I wrote the following code:

```
import os
import wx
import wx.media


class TrainingUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(TrainingUI, self).__init__(parent, title="Training")
        self.media_control = None
        self.init_ui()
        self.Center()

    def start_clicked(self, evt):
        print("path = " + os.path.abspath("."))
    #file_to_play = 'C:\\Users\\ralph\\files\\programming\\ImpactEmbedded\\senecadevices\\easy-shift-automation\\EasyShiftController\\LSDSHN.mpg'
    #file_to_play = '/home/pi/SenecaDevices/easy-shift-automation/EasyShiftController/sample-mp4-file.mp4'
    #file_to_play = "sample-mp4-file.mp4"
    file_to_play = "LSDSHN.mpg"
    print("Path exists: ")                  # find out if the program thinks the file exists
    print(os.path.exists(file_to_play))
    if not self.media_control.Load(file_to_play):
            print("media load failed")
    else:
            self.media_control.Play()

    def init_ui(self):
        # the main_screen_panel holds all the controls and sizers;
        # we arrange their placement on it with the sizers, defined later.
        main_screen_panel = wx.Panel(self)

        start_btn = wx.Button(main_screen_panel, label="Start")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.start_clicked)

        control_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        control_box.Add(start_btn)

        # the prompt, error message, and the video panel
        video_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.media_control = wx.media.MediaCtrl(main_screen_panel, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=wx.Size(250, 150), szBackend="") # , szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_DIRECTSHOW)
        video_box.Add(self.media_control)

        big_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        big_box.Add(control_box)
        big_box.Add(video_box, border=10, flag=wx.ALL)

        # outermost_box has a label across the top of the main window, and a 'big box' below containing everything else

        outermost_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        outermost_box.Add(wx.StaticText(main_screen_panel, label="wx.media test"), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        outermost_box.Add(big_box)

        main_screen_panel.SetSizer(outermost_box)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = TrainingUI(None, title="traaiin")
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I run it as follows:

```
project_directory $ ls -l LSDSHN.mpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 21665792 Jul 23 11:35 LSDSHN.mpg

project_directory $ python training_ui_video.py
path = /home/pi/SenecaDevices/easy-shift-automation/EasyShiftController
Path exists: 
True
media load failed
```

When it runs, it immediately pops up a message dialog saying "Got an invalid playbin (error 2: No such file or directory)"; this appears on top of the main screen for the program. It has an OK button to close it. I don't know where this error comes from, just loading the program doesn't attempt to load the video file, is there something else indicated by "invalid playbin"?

On the main screen of the program, I have the button and a black border around the media control, as coded. When I click the 'Start' button, I get the text below the program invocation as shown above (starting with 'path = ...')

I have also tried with an MP4 file, same result.

I found one SO post about the invalid playbin message; one answer said that wxPython must be compiled with the correct libraries. I didn't compile it (I heard it takes 10 hours on a Pi), but installed it from a .whl file that I understood to be correct - ""; I also had to search for a gstreamer package and ended up with "apt-get install python-wxgtk-media3.0", which eliminated a message I was getting when attempting to import wx.media.

What can I do to play video within a python program as above, either with this approach or another one. Ideally, I would have control programmatically over start, stop, pause, play different videos, etc.

Comment: first try `/full/path/to/video`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you found other SO post then you could add link in question.

Comment: @furas I did try full path, same result. I don't know what you're talking about in terms of a 'full error message'; for the popup dialog containing a message, I gave the entire message. There hasn't been any traceback. And until I made this comment, I hadn't made one, so I hadn't put the error message (or anything else) into a comment.

Comment: as I remeber compliation of `wxpython` takes 10 hours even on my old laptop with Intel i5

Comment: as for text `"always put ... in comment"` - I don't write it manually but I has special key shortcut to put it because I have to put it tens times every day - and I put `"in question (not in comment)"` because beginners always put important informations in comments instead of questions :)

Comment: `wxpython` seems nice module but `PyQt` doesn't need compilation. I didn't try to use `wx.media` or similar module in `PyQt`. I have only example with displaying stream from `OpenCV` - [wxPython-CV-widget](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/wxPython-CV-widget/main.py). It uses timer to read frame by frame and `paint` in window.

Comment: I tested code on Linux Mint on notebook and it works for me. I can't test it on RPi - I have some RPi but I installed system without GUI so it can't run wxpython or any other GUI framework.

Comment: The RPI stackexchange suggests `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-tools` to install gstreamer.